# Use of する to describe one's colour

Tags: words, definitions, possession

From Japanesepod101:

> 象は灰色をしている。
>
> The elephant is gray.

The meaning of the sentence is not in doubt but I've been trying to figure how する is being used here. Checking a [dictionary](http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/leaf/jn2/120514/m0u/%E3%81%99%E3%82%8B/), definition 2エ might be applicable here.

ある状態・性質であることを示す。(To show something's state/nature)

Comment: Maybe I should be asking a new question, but native speakers: how natural do you found this sentence compared to 象は灰色だ? I find 灰色をしている unnatural unless the 灰色 is modified, as in 像は綺麗な灰色をしていた.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It is exactly as you say.

「～～をする」 can mean "***to have ~~ (as a natural characteristic)***" and it is usually used in the form 「～～をしている」,「～～をしていた」 or 「～～をした」.

The "dictionary" form 「～～をする」 would ***not*** be used in a real-life situation; It is only found in dictionaries or a place like this where grammar or vocabulary is discussed.

Among those forms, 「～～をした」 is always followed immediately by a noun or noun phrase.  You cannot end a sentence with 「～～をした」 when 「する」 is used for the meaning we are discussing.  That is to say:

Always use 「している」 for the present tense and
always use 「していた」 for the past.

> している：「スミ子さんはきれいな[目]{め}をしている。」= "Sumiko has beautiful eyes."
>
> していた：「[犯人]{はんにん}は[青]{あお}い目をしていた。」= "The culprit had blue eyes."
>
> した：「[赤]{あか}い[髪]{かみ}をした[人]{ひと}が[好]{す}きです。」= "I like redheads."  Or more literally, "I like people who have read hair."