# How to describe someone who has a "radio voice"?

Tags: words, slang

I would like to tell someone to talk more, because she has a radio voice.
The term I am looking for should be either non-formal or slang.

Comment: Have you listened to Japanese radio, just to make sure "radio voice" is actually how you want to describe this someone's voice?

Comment: Assuming you mean something like "a voice for radio", you should probably confirm beforehand that it won't be taken to be derogatory as some radio announces to some, sound horrible. If you really must, something along the lines of　あなた・君{きみ} ・＿＿さん・ちゃん・君{くん}　の声｛こえ｝はラジオアナウンサーの声{こえ}みたいだからもっと喋{しゃべ}って would probably get your message across. Although it is difficult to understand the exact context you are trying to say this in and whether the other person will take offence with being compared to a radio DJ.

Answer (score 2):

If you want a noun phrase, you could use:

> 「ラジオ[向]{む}きの[声]{こえ}」
>
> 「ラジオに向いている声」
>
> 「ラジオに向いてる声」

All are natural-sounding, stress-free phrases.

If you want to form a sentence like "You have a ~~~ voice.", here is the perfect expression:

[Use of する to describe one's colour](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/23234/use-of-%e3%81%99%e3%82%8b-to-describe-ones-colour/23235#23235)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if I understand "radio voice" correctly but it might be...

> 「[声優]{せいゆう}みたいな[声]{こえ}」

声優 means voice actor or actress.

If you want to praise his/her voice, than I prefer you to tell so. It's hard to imply why you say that.

> I like your voice / [君]{きみ}の声が[好]{す}きだ
>
> You're voice is cute / [可]{か}[愛]{わい}い声だね