# How would どこ吹く風 be used in a sentence?

Tags: grammar

I know that it means that the person don't really care, but the sample sentence I keep seeing with it, 私の忠告にどこ吹く風という顔だ, doesn't really make clear how it's meant to be used. Anyone have any clues?

Answer (score 3):

どこ吹く風 is an idiomatic set phrase like "when in Rome", so grammatically you can treat it as a long noun, a no-adjective or a quote, without changing it a bit.

> - 彼はどこ吹く風だ。
> - 彼はどこ吹く風の口調だ。
> - 彼はどこ吹く風といった様子だ。
> - 彼はどこ吹く風という顔だ。
> - 彼はどこ吹く風のようだ。
> - 彼は私の話を、どこ吹く風と受け流した。

In case you don't know ～顔だ/～顔をしている, please read: [Describing facial expression](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/42349/5010)

There are many other idiomatic set phrases that work just like this:

- [我関せず](http://jisho.org/word/%E6%88%91%E9%96%A2%E3%81%9B%E3%81%9A)
- [心ここにあらず](http://jisho.org/word/%E5%BF%83%E3%81%93%E3%81%93%E3%81%AB%E3%81%82%E3%82%89%E3%81%9A)
- [我が意を得たり](http://jisho.org/word/%E6%88%91%E3%81%8C%E6%84%8F%E3%82%92%E5%BE%97%E3%81%9F%E3%82%8A)
- [知らぬが仏](http://jisho.org/word/%E7%9F%A5%E3%82%89%E3%81%AC%E3%81%8C%E4%BB%8F)

Answer (score 0):

It means

> 私の忠告｛ちゅうこく｝を聞いても彼はどこ吹く風という感じだ。

similar phrase

> 私が話してもまるで馬の耳に念仏{ねんぶつ}だ。
>
> 私が話しているのに彼はしかとしているのだろうか。

Answer (score 0):

> 私の忠告に**どこ吹く風**という顔だ

私の忠告に is made by omitting あなたに対する / あなたへの from 私の**あなたに対する**忠告に which means "*to my advice for you*".
In this sentence, 忠告 implies **a wind blowing**.
If you write どこ吹く風という顔だ fully, it will become あなたは、「風はどこに吹いていますか？」という顔だ which means *you look like saying "where is the wind blowing?"*
顔 means 様子｛ようす｝ / 態度｛たいど｝ *an appearance, a look or a manner*.

The writer of the sentence 私の忠告にどこ吹く風という顔だ wants to say that *it's impossible you don't notice the wind blowing, because it is blowing to you* or あなたは私の忠告を無視しているようである *you seem to ignore my advice*.