# The purpose of で in this context?

Tags: meaning, particles

I've stumbled across this line in a short novel and all of a sudden, everything I've learnt so far as a student in the language has gone out the window by something as simple as the "で" particle.

> 「美咲{みさき}のそういう冷たい顔で暑苦しい所、本当にキモいと思うけど、結構好きだよボク？」

From what I can gather, it almost feels like で should be translated as something like "yet or "but" here, but I'm not aware of any usages of "で" with this sort of nuance.

> "A cold expression like that on Misaki yet[?] In a hot place, I think it's really gross but I kinda like it?"

I'm not sure, the whole first part "美咲のそういう冷たい顔で暑苦しい所"  seems a mess when I try to translate it in my head and I think it's because the で is causing me confusion, so it would be great if someone could point out where I'm going wrong :)

Answer (score 1):

で on its own does not have the nuance of "but" or "yet". Here this で is simply [the te-form of the copula](http://www.japaneseprofessor.com/reference/grammar/conjugations-of-the-japanese-copula/). ～顔だ and ～顔をしている are common expressions in Japanese (see: [Describing facial expression](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/42349/5010)).

Basically 冷たい顔で暑苦しい (literally "being sultry (while) having a cold face") is a kind of [oxymoronic](https://www.thoughtco.com/awfully-good-examples-of-oxymorons-1691814) expression and should be treated as such. Explicitly inserting "but" in a rhetoric expression like "bitter sweet" is awful, isn't it?