# Meaning of ハートしている

Tags: meaning, expressions, katakana, manga, sports

In a boxing match, a trainer is telling a boxer to stay away from the opponent and wait the end of the round to recover, but he doesn't listen to him. Then the trainer says this sentence:

> どんなハートしてんだよ、兵動【ひょうどう】！！

What is the meaning of this expression? Does `ハート` mean `heart` here, or is it the abbreviation of something else? [Here is the page it is taken from](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2g0IM.jpg). Thank you for your help!

Comment: `the trainer says this sentence` -- It's uttered by (one of) the spectators, no?

Comment: @Chocolate In the previous pages, his trainer is seen shouting from the corner of the ring, so I am not sure here who is saying the sentence in question. That's why I am also not sure if きいてねェ is from 聞く or 効く. He is not listening or the punches are not effective?

Comment: 「全然きいてねえ！つか前進してる！」<- It's 効いてねえ. The punches are not effective to him... "The punches don't work on him!" or "He's not damaged at all!" I think it was uttered by the spectators, too..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

する can often be translated into English as "to have". See: [Meaning of 顔をする?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/24713/5010) and [Use of する to describe one's colour](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/23234/5010)

> - 長い髪をした人
> - 丸い形をしたコップ
> - 複雑な構造をしたプログラム
> - 緑色をした服
> - 彼は戸惑った顔をしている。

So どんなハートしてんだよ is "What kind of heart do you have?" i.e., your behavior/mentality is unbelievable.

Answer (score 1):

I think other answers explained in detail. I will analysize the meaning a little bit. The phrase goes in this way: "全然きいていねえ！！"　"つか前進している" "どんなハートしてんだよ、兵動！！". My attempt translation is "Not damaged at all!!" "Rather getting forward!" "How tough you are!" You might emphasize the boxer's resillience more explicitly in order to show boxer's gut reaction to counteract to the opponent's attack.