# How to say a pet/human has a characteristic rather than 'it is something'- How to say something has (adjective)

Tags: grammar, word-choice, adjectives

I am trying to describe what my pet looks like. Let's say her name is 'inu'. I know how to say inu is big. You would say; inu wa ookii desu. You could say what she is by putting a different adjective where ookii is. But how would I say; Inu has floppy ears. Because I basically need to know how to say my dog has a characteristic rather than my dog is something. Thankyou

Comment: Have you heard/seen the sentence: 象は鼻が長い

Comment: **Highly** related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/23234/use-of-%e3%81%99%e3%82%8b-to-describe-ones-colour/23235#23235